# Testing golang folder structure

Tags: go

My folders are structured as follows:

```
src/
   github.com/
              hello/
                   hello.go
                   hello_test.go 
                   integers/
                            integers.go
                            integers_test.go
```

`hello.go/hello_test.go` belong to package main
`integers.go/integers_test.go` belong to package integers

When runing `go test` from the root of folder hello, it only runs `hello_test.go`. How can I get it to run all tests recursively. Is this the right way to structure tests inside their respective packages?

Comment: Try `go test ./...`

Comment: that worked!! any where i can read why ? :/

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths : `Relative patterns are also allowed, like "go test ./..." to test all subdirectories. See 'go help packages' for details on the pattern syntax.`

Comment: `go help test` explains this, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

How about having a make file? In the future if you expand your project and have more test files then you can test all of them at once by just running `make test`.
This [link](https://sohlich.github.io/post/go_makefile/) would be helpful.

Comment: This is unnecessary additional complexity & dependency when you can just run `go test ./...` regardless of how many test files/packages you have.

Comment: @Adrian Note that you may want to have all sorts of parameters specified, such as how long the test should run for (i.e. `-t 25s`) and in my team we use many variables (as one does in Kubernetes) so we also add such to the `makefile`...